# getting azure storage pure javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, azure

I search an easy way to get a compile pure javascript file(s) for working with azure storage (blob/datalake) without npm/node?

I have old/new websites in .net.
When I want to work with azure, samples and libraries are great for c#. But when you require javascript (in a web browser front-end way), it look like you require to work with npm and node.

I search the easiest way to use the sdk for a team that never used NPM and node.

Comment: Marking it for closure but providing a comment nonetheless - SDK supports both Node and browser-based JS. If you don't want to use the SDK, then you can simply write your own JS code to consume Storage REST API as the SDK is simply a wrapper over the same.

Comment: I'm more questionning how to use SDK, for browser-based JS, without npm?

Comment: That’s not how I read your question. Can you please edit your question?

Comment: I edit my question, is it ok?

Comment: Please see this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/documentation/Bundling.md. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more description for @Gaurav Mantri's comment. You can use @azure/storage-blob package which is browser compatible. Previously, [azure-storage](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/) was used but now it got deprecated.

The client library in JavaScript is to consume Microsoft Azure Storage Blob service. client libraries in this package provides:-

- Get/Set Blob Service Properties
- Create/List/Delete Containers
- Create/Read/List/Update/Delete Block Blobs
- Create/Read/List/Update/Delete Page Blobs
- Create/Read/List/Update/Delete Append Blobs

To use this client library in the browser, first you need to use a [bundler](https://aka.ms/AzureSDKBundling) which converts the code to work for browser.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Azure Storage Blob client library for JavaScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob)
2. [Bundling Azure SDK libraries for a browser)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/documentation/Bundling.md)

Comment: I'v test those, deprecated lib. its working but for how long? for the moment, I use npm and webpack (like your last link) for creating a bundle with storage-blob and inject class (window.BlockBlobClient = BlockBlobClient;). I can add this lib into old website and work with azure and use latest sdk.